# Al escribir en el browser Chrome, pulsa tabulador para buscar en el sitio

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-web

Al utilizar el navegador `Chrome` (no sé en los demás) me doy cuenta que al empezar a escribir ciertos sitios de Internet (como Wikipedia, Google, Bing… incluso Stack Overflow) en su barra de navegación y antes de cargar la página sale **"Pulsa Tabulador para buscar en X sitio"**, a la derecha y en la propia barra de navegación. Por ejemplo, si estoy queriendo entrar a la URL de Stack Overflow y presiono la tecla `Tab` cambia lo que está escrito por algo como `"Buscar Stack Overflow es español |"` en color azul y a continuación el cursor titilando para ingresar allí *"el término de búsqueda"*.

Esto aparece porque dichos sitios poseen una búsqueda interna, pero he intetado con otros sitios que también tienen su propia búsqueda interna y no pasa esto de mostrar **"Pulsa Tabulador para buscar en X sitio"**. Yo tengo en mi sitio una búsqueda interna también, pero no aparece el mensaje de **"Pulsa Tabulador para buscar en X sitio"**, entonces mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo lograr que mi sitio también tenga la posibilidad de buscar algún término desde la propia barra de navegación del navegador sin tener que entrar al sitio? No sé cómo se logra eso. Si es algo que hay que configurar desde el propio navegador, o bien, debo tocar el código de mi página en donde está mi `input type "search"`. Quizás se trate sólo de agregar algún que otro atributo a dicho tag, o bien, es algo más complicado de hacer.

No sé si esto puede ayudar o tiene que ver con lo que quiero hacer, porque también estaba viendo, que si se hace clic derecho en la barra de búsqueda en donde se escribir la URL (siempre en `Chrome`) aparece la opción "Editar motores de búsqueda…" y al seleccionar dicha opción aparece una segunda lista que dice "Otros motores de búsqueda" con un botón allí de "Añadir". El problema es que no sé qué debería poner en el tercer campo que dice "URL con %s en el lugar de la consulta". Igual no sé si esto es para lo del **"Pulsa Tabulador para buscar en X sitio"**.

Answer (score 1):

Es configuración del navegador chrome.

1. Debes añadir un motor de busqueda
2. Agrega un motor de búsqueda yo en mi caso ingresé estos datos en el formulario:

   **Motor de búsqueda:** opensupport.com.bo
   **Palabra clave:** shop
   **URL con %s en lugar de la consulta:** http://www.opensupport.com.bo/shop?search=%s

Debes conocer la variable de tu sitio web o url cuando se realiza una búsqueda. Ejemplo: http://www.opensupport.com.bo/shop?search=CABLE